# Postgres index stats - last used date

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

```
SELECT
  indexrelid::regclass::text as index, 
  relid::regclass::text as table 
FROM pg_stat_user_indexes 
JOIN pg_index USING (indexrelid) 
WHERE idx_scan = 0 
AND relid::regclass::text = 'creatives'
ORDER BY index;
```

I am using the above simple query to make sure the index is used or not.  Is there a way how to get the `last_date` index been used?

Comment: No, you cannot get the date an object was created modified or used, because PostgreSQL doesn't store that information.